# Dev Express Loading Decorator causing memory leak + run time exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress, desktop-application

1) I have some performance problems using dx:LoadingDecorator , in order to demonstrate that I created a small sample app. So the problem is that every time I show a loading splash screen, a new instance of LoadingDecorator  is being pushed in the Visual Tree, gets allocated in the memory and it will never be disposed. On the next run, a new instance will be created. This behavior is leading to memory leaks.

The xaml code is :

```
<dx:DXWindow x:Class="DXApplication12.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1525">
<Grid>
    <dx:SimpleButton Width="100"
                     Height="20"
                     Content="Command"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                     Command="{Binding SimpleButtonCommand}"/>
    <dx:LoadingDecorator
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        IsSplashScreenShown="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="Loading ..." FontSize="30" Background="Transparent"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate>
    </dx:LoadingDecorator>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : DXWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        this.ContentRendered += (s, e) =>
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
              {
                  (this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel).SimpleButtonCommand.Execute(null);
              }
          };
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public ICommand SimpleButtonCommand => new DelegateCommand(() => {
        this.IsBusy = true;
        this.IsBusy = false;
    });

    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get => this._isBusy;
        set => this.SetProperty(ref this._isBusy, value, nameof(this.IsBusy));
    }
}
```

2) Another aspect is that randomly, the application raises a run time exception : 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource.

This thing happens only when the application is being started using Visual Studio and if I disable the UI Debugging Tools for XAML the problem dissapear, but I consider this a workaround and I would like to know the root cause :)

I have attached also a photo to describe the two issues that I've encountered : https://ibb.co/iJ057H

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I was facing the exact same issues. The second issue (random InvalidOperationException) is also discussed in several thread on the DevExpress support forum (e.g. [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T573499/loadingdecorator-with-gridcontrol-inside-raises-invalidoperationexception-in-a-certain) and [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T380422/splashdialog-will-often-freeze-an-almost-empty-application)), but the only workaround suggested by DevExpress is to disable the XAML Debugger.

I worked around these issues by not hiding/showing the LoadingDecorator when the busy state changes, but keeping it 'visible' all the time by setting `IsSplashScreenShown="True"` and changing the visibility of the LoadingDecorator's content instead. You can use the `SplashScreenDataContext` property to pass your view model as the data context to the decorator's content to access your `IsBusy` property.

This way there is only one permanent instance of the decorator, which fixes the memory issue. It also seems to fix the random exception, because that only occurs when the decorator is loaded.

So in your case this would look like this:

```
<Grid>
    <dx:SimpleButton .../>
        <dx:LoadingDecorator
            ...
            IsSplashScreenShown="True"
            SplashScreenDataContext="{Binding}">
            <dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ...>
                        <TextBlock .../>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate>
        </dx:LoadingDecorator>
</Grid>
```